# SSIS: Mismatched quotes error

Tags: ssis

I am trying to get this DTEXEC statement to work:

```
DTExec /REP E /f Congrat.dtsx 
/CONNECTION AcadProfDW;"\"Data Source=###########;User ID=######;
Password=##########;Initial Catalog=AcadProfDW;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;
Persist Security Info=True;Auto Translate=False;\"" 
/Set \Package.Variables[Project::CsvInputFilePath].Properties[Value];
"d:\directory\"
```

I get this error:

```
The argument "\Package.Variables[Project::CsvInputFilePath].Properties[Value];d:\directory " has mismatched quotes.
```

I've tried placing a quote before '\Package', adding an extra quote at the end, around the semicolon, and myriad other variations and I keep getting that error.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write your /Set param as follows:

```
/Set \Package.Variables[Project::CsvInputFilePath].Properties[Value];
"d:\directory\\"
```

or

```
"/Set \Package.Variables[Project::CsvInputFilePath].Properties[Value];
d:\directory\\"
```

There is an SO question on this, here is the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3348557